# Calculate Normals in Shader

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glsl, shader

I am new to OpenGL and Shaders.

I want to write a toon shader.

I have this OpenGL code:

```
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    float black[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
    float red[] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
    float green[] = { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
    float blue[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    float white[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    float lowAmbient[] = { 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0 };
    float fullAmbient[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };


    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, blue);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, blue);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, white);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 128.0);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, lowAmbient);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -9);
    glRotatef(45, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(45, 0, 0, 1);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    //front
    glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    //back
    glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    //right
    glNormal3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    //left
    glNormal3f(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    //top
    glNormal3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    //bottom
    glNormal3f(0.0, -1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, -1.0);

    glEnd();

    //Swap back and front buffer
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_LOCAL_VIEWER, GL_TRUE);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    float ambientLight[] = { 0.2,0.2,0.2,1.0 };
    float diffuseLight[] = { 0.8,0.8,0.8,1.0 };
    float specularLight[] = { 1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0 };
    float lightPosition[] = { 0.5,0.5,0.0,1.0 };
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambientLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, specularLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition);
}
```

My Shader Codes:

```
#shader vertex
#version 330 core

void main()
{

}

#shader fragment
#version 330 core

vec3 LightPosition = gl_LightSource[0].position;//I don't know this is true or not

vec3 Normal;//I don't know how to calculate


void main()
{
    vec4 color1 = gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse + gl_FrontMaterial.specular +         
    gl_FrontMaterial.ambient;
    vec4 color2;

    float intensity = dot(LightPosition, Normal);

    if (intensity > 0.95)      color2 = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    else if (intensity > 0.75) color2 = vec4(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0);
    else if (intensity > 0.50) color2 = vec4(0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.0);
    else if (intensity > 0.25) color2 = vec4(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1.0);
    else                       color2 = vec4(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0);

    gl_FragColor = color1 * color2;
}
```

To calculate light intensity and apply colors to my cube object I should know normals.
How can I calculate, or if there is a way, reach them?

(I have no problem with the shader compilation, or other OpenGL stuff. If I close my shader compilation lines I can see a green cube.)

Comment: It is not possible to combine legacy OpenGL (`glVertex3f`, ...) and a `#version 330 core` shader.

Comment: @Rabbid76 As I said, I am newbie. I am learning from YouTube and I saw like this.

Comment: Because you are using the deprecated fixed function pipeline, you cannot use your OpenGL code. You have to rewrite it. I recommend to read a good tutorial. My favorite one is [LearnOpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/)

Comment: @Rabbid76 OK, I have a look. Thank you!